# Histogram with overlaid PDF

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

Following up from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56015457/plotting-a-histogram-with-overlaid-pdf), the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns


length = 1000
np.random.seed(100)

dictOne = {
           "A": np.random.randn(length),
           "B": np.random.randn(length),
           "C": np.random.randn(length)
           }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dictOne)

column = 'B'

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df2[df2[column] > -999].hist(column, alpha = 0.5, density = False, ax = ax, bins = 100)
param = stats.norm.fit(df2[column].dropna())   # Fit a normal distribution to the data
x = np.linspace(*df2[column].agg([min, max]), 1000) # x-values

pdf_fitted = (x, stats.norm.pdf(df2[column], *param))
plt.plot(x, stats.norm.pdf(x, *param), color = 'r')
```

produces
[image]
when `density = False`
and
[image]
when `density = True`.

My question is, how do I combine the histogram from the first plot, which shows the true count of each value of random number, with the curve from the second plot? Do I need to use two different y-axes, one for the counts and one for the pdf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can multiply the density by the sum of the histogram times the binwidth; this will give you the absolute values.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(100)

length = 1000

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(length, 3), columns=list("ABC"))

column = 'B'
df = df2[df2[column] > -999]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
h, edges, _ = ax.hist(df[column], alpha = 0.5, density = False, bins = 100)

param = stats.norm.fit(df[column].dropna())   # Fit a normal distribution to the data
x = np.linspace(*df[column].agg([min, max]), 1000) # x-values

binwidth = np.diff(edges).mean()
ax.plot(x, stats.norm.pdf(x, *param)*h.sum()*binwidth, color = 'r')

plt.show()
```

[image]