# Scaling a PDF to show 100% at peak

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy, probability-density

I'm displaying a histogram of my data, with an overlaid PDF. My plots all look something like this:

[image]

and I'm trying to scale the red curve to show 100% at the peak.

My following toy code is identical to what I'm actually using, apart from the lines in between the two `%`:

```
%
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np
my_randoms = np.random.normal(0.5, 1, 50000)
dictOne = {"delta z":my_randoms}
df = pd.DataFrame(dictOne)
df = df[df['delta z'] > -999]
%

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
h, edges, _ = ax.hist(df['delta z'], alpha = 1, density = False, bins = 100)

param = stats.norm.fit(df['delta z'].dropna())   # Fit a normal distribution to the data
pdf_fitted = stats.norm.pdf(df['delta z'], *param)
x = np.linspace(*df['delta z'].agg([min, max]), 100) # x-values
binwidth = np.diff(edges).mean()
ax.plot(x, stats.norm.pdf(x, *param)*h.sum()*binwidth, color = 'r')

#   Decorations
graph_title = 'U-B'
plt.grid(which = 'both')
plt.title(r'$\Delta z$ distribution for %s'%graph_title, fontsize = 25)
plt.xlabel(r'$\Delta z = z_{spec} - z_{photo}$', fontsize = 25)
plt.ylabel('Number', fontsize = 25)
plt.xticks(fontsize = 25)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 25)
xmin, xmax = min(df['delta z']), max(df['delta z'])
plt.xlim(xmin, xmax)
plt.annotate(
r'''$\mu_{\Delta z}$ = %.3f
$\sigma_{\Delta z}$ = %.3f'''%(param[0], param[1]),
         fontsize = 25, color = 'r', xy=(0.85, 0.85), xycoords='axes fraction')
```

How would I define another `axes` object from 0 to 100 on the right-hand side and map the PDF to that?
Or is there a better way to do it?

This is kind of a follow-up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56015457/plotting-a-histogram-with-overlaid-pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `density=True` in plotting the histogram.

Answer (score 0):

You use `.twinx()`:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8), dpi=72.0)

n_rows = 2
n_cols = 2

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(n_rows, n_cols, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(n_rows, n_cols, 2)

ax3 = ax1.twinx()
```

https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/two_scales.html